# How to override the max_length error message for an ImageField?

Tags: django

I am using Django 2.2.
I have an ImageField. I need to override its default max length of 100 and **override the error message it generates**.

Is it me or error messages for anything that inherits from FileField cannot be overridden?

```
class PageTemplate(models.Model)
    background_image = models.ImageField(
          blank=True,
          null=True,
          verbose_name='Header Image',
          upload_to=page_template_image_path,
          max_length=150,
          error_messages={'max_length': "This is a test 1"},
          validators=(validate_image_file_extension, validate_filename_size),
      )
```

The error message that I get is `Ensure this filename has at most 150 characters (it has 157)`. And before anybody asks, yes, I remembered to run makemigrations and migrate.

Comment: What do your validators do? Can you share the code?

Comment: @KeoniGarner The error is thrown by the FileField class before my validators. Therefore my validators are not executing.

Comment: This error message comes from the [`form fields`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/main/django/forms/fields.py#L551) so you'll have to override that.

Comment: Remove max length..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I was able to solve the issue. PageTemplateAdmin now uses PageTemplateForm and that's where I was able to override the error message.

```
    class PageTemplate(models.Model)
        background_image = models.ImageField(
              blank=True,
              null=True,
              verbose_name='Header Image',
              upload_to=page_template_image_path,
              max_length=150,
              validators=[validate_image_file_extension],
          )


    class PageTemplateForm(forms.ModelForm):
        class Meta:
            model = PageTemplate
            fields = '__all__'
            error_messages = {
                'background_image': {
                    'max_length': ('Filename has to be less than 100 characters'),
                },
            }


    class PageTemplateAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
        form = PageTemplateForm
        list_display = [...]
```